Tippecanoe Overwriting Unique Property Values Across Features
I am encountering an issue with Tippecanoe while generating vector tiles from GeoJSON data. Specifically, the uprn property of the second feature is being replaced with the uprn of the first feature. This occurs when generating tiles with the following command:
Command:
tippecanoe --no-feature-limit --buffer=64 --no-tile-size-limit --force --force-feature-limit --no-tile-size-limit --include=uprn --attribute-type=uprn:string --minimum-zoom=5 --maximum-zoom=16 --drop-rate=0.5 --layer=layername --output-to-directory "tiles" .simple-zero.geojson

GeoJSON Sample:
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [0.2695046458, 51.1373675861]
      },
      "properties": {
        "uprn": "100062108583",
        "parking_spaces": 0,
        "address": "FLAT 3, 139, CAMDEN ROAD, TUNBRIDGE WELLS, TN1 2RA",
        "property_class": "RD06",
        "parkable_area": 48.709404,
        "postcode": "TN1 2RA"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [0.4840589415, 51.2704560878]
      },
      "properties": {
        "uprn": "10022901830",
        "parking_spaces": 0,
        "address": "FLAT 8, KINGSWOOD HOUSE, MARIGOLD WAY, MAIDSTONE, ME16 0GA",
        "property_class": "RD06",
        "parkable_area": 76.709114,
        "postcode": "ME16 0GA"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Issue:
When generating tiles, the second feature’s uprn (10022901830) gets replaced by the first feature's uprn (100062108583). The other properties are retained correctly, but this issue is causing a duplication of the uprn value across both features.
Expected Result:
The uprn of each feature should remain unique and retain its original value from the GeoJSON input.
Steps Taken:

I ensured the uprn property is included and set as a string using --include=uprn and --attribute-type=uprn:string.
I used the --no-feature-limit and --no-tile-size-limit options to avoid any potential feature limitations.
Tested with different zoom levels and tile generation configurations, but the issue persists.

Could you please provide guidance on how to fix this issue or whether there might be a bug affecting the handling of unique properties across features?
Thank you for your assistance!
